# Cygwin git rebase fail?

Tags: git, cygwin, git-rebase

If I run

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

The editor comes up with just

```
git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

Instead of the commits. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you set the config option `core.editor`, or are any of the environment variables `GIT_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` set?  If so, what are their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=
fi
Notepad2 ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is not empty, convert to Windows format.

Then I set these variables:

```c
export EDITOR=notepad2.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/notepad2.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/2973070/editor)